# How to handle duplicates using foreachBatch in spark structured streaming in case of stream termination?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks, delta-lake

I have a stream that uses foreachBatch and keeps checkpoints in a data lake, but if I cancel the stream, it happens that the last write is not fully commited. Then the next time I start the stream I get duplicates, since it starts from the last commited batchId.

I use delta but I don't want to use the merge because I have a lot of data and it doesn't seem to be as performant as I would like (even using partitions).

How can I use the batchId to handle the duplicates? Or is there some other way?

Comment: Is there any reason you cannot use `writeStream.format("delta").(...)`? The Delta sink will help you handle this automatically.

Comment: @zsxwing I do use `writeStream.format("delta").foreachBatch(process_to_dl).(...)` but I append all the rows to the detla table. I don't understand what you mean by the Delta sink will handle it automatically, can you clarify?

Comment: `format("delta")` and `foreachBatch` cannot be used at the same time. `foreachBatch` is like `format("foreachBatch")`. Use `format("delta")` should be enough unless you need to do complicated things in `process_to_dl`.